# how to create dynamic http body in elm

Tags: api, elm

I am implementing the service where i have to create the dynamic http post request and my code is below.

```
postRequest: Int -> Http.Request
postRequest catId = 
        let
            body =
                """{"categoryId:"""++catId++""","coupon":false,"domainId":1,"locations":[],"onlineMenu":false,"onlineOrder":false,"pageNo":1,"pageSize":10,"reservation":false,"searchText":"","subcategories":[]}"""
        in 
           {    verb = "POST"
                , headers =
                    [("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    ]
                , url = "http://xyz/businesses/list"
                , body = Http.string body
            }
```

but i am getting some error 
how to concatenate the catId in the body and catId is integer type.

please anyone suggest what i have did wrong in the implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you declared `catId` as `Int` not `String`, so
`(++) : String -> String -> String` cannot not work on it.

You can use `toString : a -> String` before concatenating it with strings.

```
"categoryId:" ++ (toString catId)
```

Comment: Thanks @Tosh for your help !!